# Prove $32 \sin^6 x = -15 \cos (2x) + 6 \cos (4x) - \cos (6x) + 10$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I already tried to do it, but my answer is incorrect! This is how I do it.

> assuming 
>   $$2 \cos x = z + \frac1z\space\space\text{ and }\space\space 2j \sin x = z - \frac1z$$
>   $$(2j \sin x)^6 \cdot \frac12 = \left(z - \frac1z\right)^6 \cdot \frac12$$
>   $$32j \sin^6 x \cdot \frac12 = \left(z - \frac1z\right)^6 \cdot \frac12$$
>   I expanded $(z - \frac1z)^6$ using pascal's triangle, however this is what I got:
>   $$z^6 + \frac1{z^6} - 6 \left(z^4 + \frac1{z^4}\right) + 15 \left(z^2 + \frac1{z^2}\right) - 20$$
>   $$2 \cos {6x} - 12 \cos {4x} + 30 \cos {2x} - 20$$
>   multiply it with $\frac12$, final answer is:
>   $$\cos {6x} - 6 \cos {4x} + 15 \cos {2x} - 10$$

The "+" and "-" signs seems to be reversed compared to the actual answer, however I don't know what I did wrong! Can anyone help me?

Sorry for bad question format, I'm new to using StackExchange. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Well, this is apparently electronics, so $j = \sqrt{-1}$.  Note that $j^6 \ne j$.

Comment: If $j$ is the imaginary unit, how can the statement be true?  When $x$ is real the right hand side is real and the left-hand side is pure imaginary.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I figured it out! I forgot to raise j to the power of six and j^2 = -1. Thank you very much! Anyway, the question is supposed to be 32 sin^6 x, not 32j sin^6 x. My bad!

Comment: Do you still have a question?

Comment: I'm good, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2\sin^2x = 1- \cos2x$

So,

> $8\sin^6x = (2\sin^2x)^3 = (1-\cos2x)^3 = 1 - 3\cos2x+3\cos^2(2x)-\cos^3(2x)$

Now, $\cos^2A = \frac{1+\cos(2A)}{2}$ and $\cos^3(A) = \frac{\cos(3A) + 3\cos(A)}{4}$

So, $8\sin^6x = 1 -3\cos(2x)+ 3\frac{1+\cos(4x)}{2}-\frac{\cos(6x) + 3\cos(2x)}{4}$

Multipying both sides by $4$

$32\sin^6x  = 4 - 12\cos(2x) + 6 + 6\cos(4x) - \cos(6x) - 3\cos(2x)$

> $$32\sin^6x = -15\cos(2x)+6\cos(4x)- \cos(6x)+10$$